# About the man usage

Tags: manpage

```
man 3p printf
man 3 printf
```

The above two man page gives different info of `printf`.

What's different for `man 3` and `man 3p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ man -k printf | grep '^printf'
printf (1)           - format and print data
printf (1posix)      - write formatted output
printf (3)           - formatted output conversion
printf (3posix)      - print formatted output
```

You have probably installed the `manpages-posix` and `manpages-posix-dev` packages on your system, as I have. This also gives you the POSIX-prepared manpages, which is an excellent way to determine if you're relying on behavior specific to your system or standardized behavior.

Comment: `format and print data|write formatted output|formatted output conversion|print formatted output`, aren't they talking about the same thing?

Comment: @compile-fan, sure thing :) but one is written by someone trying to document the GNU glibc implementation, and one was written by someone trying to document the POSIX standardized version that should be available on _all_ POSIX-compliant platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can find the answer to this yourself with:

```
man man
```

---

But what is happening is your system defines `3` and `3p` as separate sections. This is generally used for "package" man pages, e.g. for the POSIX package.